# Set-AzVMRunCommand succeeded but Invoke-AzVMRunCommand failed for unknown reason

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I can use `Set-AzVMRunCommand` to create a command (successfully) on Azure VM. I am wondering how to invoke it (more than once)?

```
Set-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VMName $vmName -Location $location -RunCommandName "foobar" -ScriptLocalPath ".\Run-App.ps1" -RunAsUser $vmUser -RunAsPassword $vmPass
```

I see my command is created successfully:

```json
>> az vm run-command list --resource-group "hvtt1" --vm-name "testvm"

[
  {
    "asyncExecution": false,
    "errorBlobManagedIdentity": null,
    "errorBlobUri": null,
    "id": "/subscriptions/c1097bf0-4f64-4ee0-b922-7dd05a5965fe/resourceGroups/hvtt1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testvm/runCommands/foobar",
    "instanceView": null,
    "location": "eastus2",
    "name": "foobar",
    "outputBlobManagedIdentity": null,
    "outputBlobUri": null,
    "parameters": null,
    "protectedParameters": null,
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "resourceGroup": "hvtt1",
    "runAsPassword": null,
    "runAsUser": "user",
    "source": {
      "commandId": null,
      "script": "Write-Host \"Finished script initialization\";",
      "scriptUri": null,
      "scriptUriManagedIdentity": null
    },
    "tags": null,
    "timeoutInSeconds": 0,
    "treatFailureAsDeploymentFailure": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommands"
  }
]
```

But I can't invoke it where I use ARM ID of the command as $id

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand         `
  -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup        `
  -VMName $vmName                          `
  -CommandId $id -Verbose
```

Error I am getting:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Invoke" on target "testvm".
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand : The entity was not found in this Azure location.
ErrorCode: NotFound
ErrorMessage: The entity was not found in this Azure location.
ErrorTarget: 
StatusCode: 404
ReasonPhrase: 
OperationID : 6ae3c2f5-7328-4de1-b1d2-a78d85576351
At line:12 char:1
+ Invoke-AzVMRunCommand         `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Invoke-AzVMRunCommand], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.InvokeAzureRmVMRunCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I can't invoke it where I use ARM ID of the command as $id

```
ErrorMessage: The entity was not found in this Azure location.
```

Alternatively, you can also use az vm run-command create to execute a script on the VM with the existing VM resource ID.

```
 az vm run-command create --resource-group  "myResourceGroup"  --location  "West US"  --command-id
```

After running the above command, you can list all deployed `RunCommand` resources on a `VM` by using the command below.

```
az vm run-command list --vm-name  "myVM"  --resource-group  "myRG"
```

**Reference**:  [Run scripts in your Windows VM by using managed Run Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command-managed)

[az vm run-command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#commands)